# How to add equal space between all of the boxes in this grid?

Tags: html, css, grid, spacing

I am trying to create a landing page and right now I have placeholder images in each box, but I am trying to add some space between those boxes. How can I create spaces between all of the boxes created and also allow for it to be responsive? My idea is to create a container and mess with the margins and padding but it messes it up for mobile view.

```css
.twocolumn {
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.twocolumn2 {
    width: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.onecolumn {
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.twocolumn h2 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: passion one;
    color: #FFF;
}

.twocolumn2  h2{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: passion One;
    color: #FFF;
}

.onecolumn h2 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: passion one;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 14px;
}


.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}

.columnimg {
    width: 100%;
}

.header {
    background: white;
    margin: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: passion one;
    font-size:5vw;
    letter-spacing: 3vw;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
        
        <a href="#"><div class="twocolumn clearfix" style="background-image:url(http://www.jennybeaumont.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/placeholder.gif); background-size:cover;height:400px;background-position:center;">
            <h2>TITLE HERE</h2>
        </div></a>
        
      <a href="#"><div class="twocolumn2 clearfix left" style="background-image:url(http://www.jennybeaumont.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/placeholder.gif); background-size:cover;height:400px;background-position:center;">
            <h2>TITLE HERE</h2>
        </div></a>
     
        <a href="#"><div class="onecolumn clearfix left" style="background-image:url(http://www.jennybeaumont.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/placeholder.gif); background-size:cover;height:200px;background-position:center;">
            <h2>TITLE HERE</h2>
        </div></a>
        
        <a href="#"><div class="onecolumn clearfix left" style="background-image:url(http://www.jennybeaumont.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/placeholder.gif); background-size:cover;height:200px;background-position:center top;">
            <h2>TITLE HERE</h2>
        </div></a>
        
        <a href="#"><div class="onecolumn clearfix left" style="background-image:url(http://www.jennybeaumont.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/placeholder.gif); background-size:cover;height:200px;background-position:center;">
            <h2>TITLE HERE</h2>
        </div></a>
        
        <a href="#"><div class="onecolumn clearfix left" style="background-image:url(http://www.jennybeaumont.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/placeholder.gif); background-size:cover;height:200px;background-position:center;">
            <h2>TITLE HERE</h2>
        </div></a>

        
        <a href="#"><div class="twocolumn clearfix" style="background-image:url(http://www.jennybeaumont.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/placeholder.gif); background-size:cover;height:400px;background-position:center;">
            <h2>TITLE HERE</h2>
        </div></a>
        
        <a href="#"><div class="onecolumn clearfix left" style="background-image:url(http://www.jennybeaumont.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/placeholder.gif); background-size:cover;height:200px;background-position:center;">
            <h2>TITLE HERE</h2>
        </div></a>
        
        <a href="#"><div class="onecolumn clearfix left" style="background-image:url(http://www.jennybeaumont.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/placeholder.gif); background-size:cover;height:200px;background-position:center;">
            <h2>TITLE HERE</h2>
        </div></a>
        
        <a href="#"><div class="onecolumn clearfix left" style="background-image:url(http://www.jennybeaumont.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/placeholder.gif); background-size:cover;height:200px;background-position:center top;">
            <h2>TITLE HERE</h2>
        </div></a>
        
        <a href="#"><div class="onecolumn clearfix left" style="background-image:url(http://www.jennybeaumont.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/placeholder.gif); background-size:cover;height:200px;background-position:center;">
            <h2>TITLE HERE</h2>
            </div></a></div>
```

Thanks for all of the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you want to do, but is there a specific reason you aren't using css-grid? It seems perfect for that.

Other than that, you basically have to use padding and margin. To not mess it up for the mobile view, use media queries. Like this:

```
@media print, screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  //this css only applies when there is at least 640px of horizontal space (common tablet width)
}
```

Edit: As request an example with css-grid: (Note: css-grid should not replace flexbox, but rather work along it. Use a combination as you see fit. With the given Information, I cannot do that)
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/SourceOverflow/pen/jGVWYM) and the same Code here:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 200px auto 200px;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "logo top-left top-right"
    "logo bottom-left bottom-right"
    "main main main"
    "bottom-row bottom-row bottom-row";
  grid-column-gap: 6px;
  grid-row-gap: 6px;
}

.logo {
  grid-area: logo;
  background-color: red;
}
.menu-top-left {
  grid-area: top-left;
  background-color: blue;
}
.menu-top-right {
  grid-area: top-right;
  background-color: blue;
}
.menu-bottom-left {
  grid-area: bottom-left;
  background-color: blue;
}
.menu-bottom-right {
  grid-area: bottom-right;
  background-color: blue;
}
.main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: green;
  
  height: 400px;
}
.bottom-row {
  grid-area: bottom-row;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="menu-top-left"></div>
  <div class="menu-top-right"></div>
  <div class="menu-bottom-left"></div>
  <div class="menu-bottom-right"></div>
  <div class="main"></div>
  <div class="bottom-row"></div>
</div>
```

This should solve that layout-problem with the gaps, but for responsiveness, you will probably still need the media queries.

Comment: I am not quite sure what css-grid is... would you be able to explain with examples?

Comment: Here is a documentation of what css-grid does: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ I will complete my answer with an example, that represents something like what I think you wanted to achieve, but it is a bit hard to see how it should look like, since you used images instead of colored backgrounds

Answer (score 0):

I would use Flexbox. Set the flex to 1 and justify-content to space-between or space-around if you want space on the ends.